# How to write lowercase 'q' with a curved tail in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, letters

I want to have two different q's for charges and generalized coordinates. How can I write 'q' with a tail like this - not just a straight one?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific in terms of what represents the tail of the lowercase q? Is it the stroke indicated by 3, or is the full descender (below the baseline) or both?

Comment: @Werner , yes, the part denoted by 3 or it's curved analog on the picture above. Either of them or something in between are fine. I just need 2 visually distinct lowercase 'q' letters for use in text. I tried \frak but it looks too similar.

Comment: If your font has the character U+024B (Latin small letter Q with hook tail), and you uses lualatex or xetex, you can obtain it (ɋ). Others solutions : use of Q, instead of q, for the charges, or displays one of the two q in the sans serif variant of the font if it is available. Can you change the font of your document or the engine or must you stick with pdflated and Computer (or Latin) modern?

Answer (score 3):

There are several fonts available eg calligra for pdflatex

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,calligra}
\begin{document}

$q\text{\calligra q}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some math script fonts available with [`mathalpha`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha) have lowercase letters. For example, here's the result with Boondox

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[scr=boondox]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\(q\mathscr{q}\)
\end{document}
```

`mathalpha` also provides a less slanted version of Boondox with the option `scr=boondoxo`. Replacing the option in the above example gives

[image]

A less fancy option would be Dutchcal (obtained with `scr=dutchcal`), although that might be less obvious to distinguish quickly in a text.

[image]